# Getting multiple divs aligned to the centre & on the same row?

Tags: html, css

So I have made a set of navigational buttons for my website in `Photoshop` and I want to centralize the buttons but using various `CSS` margin statements or float statements just centralizes the buttons but they are in a 1 x 4 column instead of on the same row (There are 4 buttons).

The banner on my site is centralized and I want the buttons to be centralized below them. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="home" class="home">
<img title="Home" src="images/images/home.jpg">
</div>

<div id="iwb" class="iwb" align="center;">
<img title="IWB" src="images/images/iwb.jpg">
</div>

<div id="presentations" class="presentations">
<img title="Presentations" src="images/images/presentations.jpg">
</div>

<div id="internet" class="internet">
<img title="internet" src="images/images/net.jpg">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.home {
display: block;
width: 188px;
height: 50px;
background: url(images/images/home.jpg) bottom;
text-indent: -99999px;
  }

.home:hover {
background-position: 0 0;
}

.iwb {
display: block;
width: 188px;
height: 50px;
background: url(images/images/iwb.jpg) bottom;
text-indent: -99999px;
}

.iwb:hover {
background-position: 0 0;
}

.presentations {
display: block;
width: 188px;
height: 50px;
background: url(images/images/presentations.jpg) bottom;
text-indent: -99999px;
}
.presentations:hover {
background-position: 0 0;
}

.internet {
display: block;
width: 188px;
height: 50px;
background: url(images/images/net.jpg) bottom;
text-indent: -99999px;

}
.internet:hover {
background-position: 0 0;

}
```

How can I get them to be centralized but all across one row directly underneath my header? I want no white space vertically between my header and navbar buttons if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want them to appear same row , you should use `display: inline-block` or `float: left` instead of `display : block` .

You can see examples in here for inline-block.

http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

**EDIT:**

When you use `display:inline-block`, you need to use `font-size:0` like below.

http://jsfiddle.net/xXVCg/1/

If you don't want to `font-size:0` , you should use `float:left` like below.

http://jsfiddle.net/xXVCg/

Comment: I can't help you more to not see images. If you can upload on jsfiddle.net with images, the problem can be solved more easily.

Comment: You can try to use ' *{margin: 0, padding: 0}  ' or reset.css file.

Comment: I would not recommend you to use center tag. If you want to center anything, after you have defined a width, you can use **margin:auto** to center. http://jsfiddle.net/Tsj2Q/1/

Comment: You can use a tag instead of div tag. like **<a id="home" class="home" href="html file link"></a>**